# User registration error in Magento 2 B2B module

Tags: magento2, b2b

I have installed Magento 2 B2B module via composer. after install, I tried to create the new user in the frontend. But I got the below error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Company\Model\Customer\Company\Interceptor::createCompany() must be of the type array, string given, called in /app/vendor/magento/module-company/Model/Plugin/AccountManagement.php on line 119 and defined in /app/generated/code/Magento/Company/Model/Customer/Company/Interceptor.php:20 Stack trace: #0 /app/vendor/magento/module-company/Model/Plugin/AccountManagement.php(119): Magento\Company\Model\Customer\Company\Interceptor->createCompany(Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer), 'kmgkumar', NULL) #1 /app/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Company\Model\Plugin\AccountManagement->afterCreateAccount(Object(Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer), Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer), 'admin@123', 'https://b2bmodu...') #2 /app/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Int in /app/generated/code/Magento/Company/Model/Customer/Company/Interceptor.php on line 20
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue, and resolved by following this:
https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/M2-2-1-Order-details-bug/td-p/93280

You have issue of Factory classes/Method.
to resolve the issue kindly follow the below steps :

```
rm -rf  var/generation
rm -rf generated
rm -rf var/cache
rm -rf var/page_cache
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: But I used a Magento cloud environment. I can't able to do the compilation process.

Comment: Which cloud environment you are working on? AWS or google or something else?

Comment: Every cloud environment give shell access, and you need to run di compile and deploy command in order to run magento2. This is most important part in magento2